# Access Query not recognizing values from sub queries

Tags: ms-access, subquery, aggregate

The following query has aggregate calculations done in sub-queries on 2 separate tables and those values are passed to the main query.

(Note the above message and the following posted code has been updated based on the  comments from Andre. The original code didn't run due to errors.)

```
SELECT
     totSales.[Month]  & " /" AS [Month], 
     totSales.[Year] AS [Year],
     SALES_REP.rep_name AS [Sales Person],
     Sum(totSales.[Total Sales]) AS [Total Sales], 
     Sum(totSales.[Gross Commission]) AS [Gross Commission],
     Sum(Nz(totReturns.[Sales Returns],0)) AS [Sales Returns],
     Sum(Nz(totReturns.[Lost Commission],0)) AS [Lost Commission],
     Round([Gross Commission]-[Lost Commission]) AS [Net Commission]

    FROM SALES_REP

     INNER JOIN
     (

    (SELECT

        Format(SALES_RECEIPT.sale_date,'yyyy') AS [Year], 
        Format(SALES_RECEIPT.sale_date,'mm') AS [Month], 
        Sales_receipt.inventory_id, SALES_RECEIPT.rep_id, 
        ( SALES_RECEIPT.selling_price *  SALES_RECEIPT.quantity) AS [Total Sales], 
        ((Nz(SALES_RECEIPT.selling_price, 0) * Nz( SALES_RECEIPT.quantity, 0)) * (Nz(SALES_RECEIPT.commission_percent, 100) * 0.001)) AS [Gross Commission]

    FROM SALES_RECEIPT
    WHERE SALES_RECEIPT.sale_date Between #1/1/2000# And #12/31/2050#) AS totSales

    LEFT JOIN

    (SELECT
        RETURNS.rep_id, returns.inventory_id, (Nz(RETURNS.selling_price)) * (Nz(RETURNS.quantity)) AS [Sales Returns],
        ((Nz(RETURNS.selling_price, 0) * Nz(RETURNS.quantity, 0)) * (Nz(RETURNS.commission_percent, 100) * 0.001)) AS [Lost Commission]

    FROM RETURNS
    WHERE RETURNS.return_date Between #1/1/2000# And #12/31/2050#)  AS totReturns
    ON totSales.inventory_id = totReturns.inventory_id)

    ON SALES_REP.rep_id = totSales.REP_ID

    GROUP BY
    totSales.[Year]
    , totSales.[Month]
    , SALES_REP.rep_name
    ;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Second try, based on your original query - all errors you got can be explained:

- `totSales.Year-Month` : you must put this in square brackets, both in the SELECT and the GROUP BY clause: `totSales.[Year-Month]`.
  Otherwise it's interpreted as `[totSales.Year] minus [Month]`.
- `SELECT SUM(totReturns.[Return Sales])` but in `totReturns` you have `AS [Returns Sales]` (note the extra "s" in Returns).
- `TotCommissions, TotLostCommissions`: Those two fields are not defined anywhere in the FROM clause.

Comment: Thanks for the update, I have my latest code posted above with a revised message.  The query runs without errors but  the "Total Sales" value is twice the value it should be. The "Sales Returns" values are incorrect with many of the "Sales Returns" values being 3 or 4 times the amount of the "Total Sales" which is way off.

Comment: If I add the Nz function to the following line of code I get the error: "Data type mismatch in criteria expression."                                                                             Nz(RETURNS.selling_price * RETURNS.quantity) AS  [Return Sales],    Since there are some months with no returns, I would like to use the Nz function so I get zeros in instead of null values.

Comment: @CodeMechanik: I can't help with the wrong numbers - perhaps a join creates duplicate records that are then summed up. You should ask that in a new question, with a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) with sample data.

Comment: @CodeMechanik: For Nz(), try using the same structure as you have for [Lost Commission] - Nz() around each column.

Comment: Thanks for all your help.  The problem has been resolved with the this line of code:  ON totSales.inventory_id = totReturns.inventory_id) for the second sub-query.  Original it was done with rep_id but it is necessary to use a different foreign key linking both tables (inventory_id is in both tables).